# i need to leave a project i committed to due to mental health decline

Tags: quitting, depression

my friend and i started our own business together and we took a project that is to complete by aug 31st. the last couple of months i have been suffering from depression and made a suicide attempt last week that ended up in me getting my stomach pumped (not going to go into it here). i did not tell my business partner this because when i told her about my depression, she ignored me and started assigning more tasks. now i completely can't do any tasks and she's pressuring me more everyday. i want to quit and concentrate on getting better. i feel like i need to put me first for a while. i know my business partner will be angry and cut our working relationship and friendship if i quit now. i am not sure what i should do. this whole situation is making things worse for me.

Comment: **Talk to a medical professional**, not the Internet.

Comment: And talk to your business partner. She has no way to estimate how serious this is for you. People say "I feel depressed" all the time now, it is very hard to know if this is a passing down or a full on depression going on if you are not personally close.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Spot on! OP - Your health comes first and mental health is no less important than physical just because it's not as visible!

Comment: Don't feel guilty over this. Most people should be understanding of your situation. One of the most important rules in life is **health > work**.

Comment: Who are the people who down voted a question asked by someone fighting depression and looking for an answer?. Do you chaps have any understanding of this situation?

Comment: It's a pity to see this question downvoted, because it seems to be asked by a really desperate person and downvoting really does not help. To the OP - please try to post this same question on quora.com - it's more suited for such questions. As to the issue - ask yourself, if your "friend" does not care about your situation, why should you care about her project, and why her "friendship" is so valuable to you.

Answer (score 5):

Your health comes first. To be as considerate as you can, let your friend know as soon as possible that your health issues are sufficiently severe that you cannot be relied on. Apologize for the inconvenience this will cause and reiterate that your health comes first.

Offer to help smooth your exit to the extent that you can do so. If you can write up planning documents, offer to do so. If you can help interview someone to do some of the work you were doing, offer to do so. If you cannot do these things, clearly and simply state that you cannot help.

Trying to do what you cannot do will not produce a good outcome. Letting someone think you will be able to provide assistance you will not be able to provide will not produce a good outcome.

Take the time you need to get better, whatever it takes. You will not get good results any other way.

Answer (score 4):

If you broke your arm, you can't carry heavy loads. If you broke your leg, you can't run quickly. Trying to do so will cause more harm than good. And it's not different for anxiety and depression disorders. This is an illness that needs a cure as well as a broken arm or leg.

So tell your business partner about your medical condition. Get a doctor to examine this and give you an attestation of your condition (and of course also to help you with your ailment). Since you already tried to commit suicide, this is an **emergency** even if you feel you can currently avoid another suicide attempt.

What would you have done if you had a severe car accident and had to stay in hospital for several weeks? Such things happen. Let your business partner be angry, that happens too. It is of no use to anybody if you end up dead from a successful suicide attempt. And even if you could avoid this and force yourself to work, the results will be of low quality.

You may have a bad conscience now, but in hindsight, you will be glad that you took the break.

Comment: Since you attempted suicide, you should be seeing a therapist now about this condition, You need to get a note from him/her detailing what you medically need in this situation.  Take that to the owner when you go to discuss this.